# Azure Function authentication using Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I wanted to enable authentication on Azure Functions. So, I decided to go with EasyAuth (Authentication/Authorization link under platform features) and was successfully able to configure the authentication process.

The authentication works when I manually sign-in to the Azure Function endpoint. But when I try to programmatically access the API, without any manual user intervention, I'm facing authentication issue:

```
Status Code:401, Unauthorized
```

I get an access token from AAD using clientID and clientSecret using the following code:

```
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>");
string key = "<client-secret>";
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("<client-id>", key);
AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://<AzureFunctionAppName>.azurewebsites.net/", cc).Result;
return result.AccessToken;
```

Then I'm trying to send the Access Token received in the header for a new request to my API:

```
var content = "{\"on\":true, \"sat\":254, \"bri\":254, \"hue\":10000}";
var AADToken = GetS2SAccessToken();
HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AADToken);
var foo = Client.PostAsync("https://<AzureFunctionAppName>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad", new StringContent(content.ToString())).Result;
Console.WriteLine($"result: {foo}");
```

But the above code is resulting in unauthorized calls. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use the accesstoken to access the you azure function api directly, if your azure function authentication level is **anonymous** or **function key** is also required.

I get the access token with your mentioned way. According to the Azure Resources portal(https://resources.azure.com/), the default allowedAudiences is

```
  "https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"
```

So I add the `https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/` as allowed aduiences

[image]

Then I can use the access token directly. I test it with postman.

[image]

We also could use the following way to get **easy auth token.** The access token is the token that you got.

```
Post https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
Content-Type:application/json
{
    "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOix...rtf2H7lyUL-g34HVw"
}
```

[image]

After that we could use the get token to access the azure function api

[image]

**Note**: Header is **x-zumo-auth**: token

Comment: I added the url to allowed audience and used postman; I'm still getting the message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page". Is it possible that I'm getting the wrong access_token from AAD? I have tried both the methods that you mentioned here

Comment: Is your azure function authentication  level anonymous? If no, you also need to add the function key. And after add the allowed audience, please get a new access token to try it again .

Comment: Hello, I was able to resolve the problem. The issue was with the AAD token generated. Passing App ID instead of  "https://<AzureFunctionAppName>.azurewebsites.net/" in context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://<AzureFunctionAppName>.azurewebsites.net/", cc).Result; helped

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the issue, you need to create a client app to call your Azure function. The detailed steps are as Below.

1. Configure Azure AD for Azure Function. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#auth.

   i. Go to Integrate of your trigger, set Authorization level to Anonymous
   [image]

   ii.    Got to Authentication / Authorization and configure Azure AD

   [image]
2. Register a clent application in AD on the azure portal. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-integrate-apps-with-azure-ad.

   a.    Open the Azure Active Directory and click the App registrations , choose New application registration.

   b.    Enter your Name and Redirect URL, you can write anything. Then click create button.

   c.    Settings-> Required permissions -> add, choose the application you use in the step1

   d.    Select permission -> APPLICAION PERMISSIONS ->Select->Done->Grant Permissions->Yes

   e.    Create a key and copy it

   f.    Copy the Application ID
3. Test

Get Token:

```
METHOD: POST

Url : https://login.microsoftonline.com/your directory ID/oauth2/token 

HEADERS:  Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

BODY:
grant_type+=client_credentials&resource+=”your Function APP ID”&client_id+++++=”the application that your register  id”&client_secret+=”the key you create”
```

Test Function:

```
METHOD: Get

Url : https://<Functionname>.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?name=azure

HEADERS:  Authorization : Bearer <access token>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thank you.

Comment: Is it Possible to Pass client_secret and Client_id in Request headers?