# Azure active directory using loginwithazureactivedirectory and expressmode

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

we want to use azure active directory for function app authetication after enabling azureactive directory express mode.we have selected loginwithazureactivedirectory option.
when we are hitting function through postman it is giving html of log in screen of micro soft.
with out that sceen cant we access the fucntion app uRL.

Please find the below screen for your reference[image]

Any help is appreciated on this

Comment: Have you tried to call it within browser? I mean paste the URL on browser and let me know what happens....

Comment: yes i have tried it is reirect to microsoft login screen

Comment: Do you still have problem? If so let me know.... you can have a look here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499971/azure-function-authentication-using-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you successfully configure Azure AD for your web app, you need to use the access token to access your application.
I get an access token from AAD using clientID and clientSecret using the following code:

```
 METHOD: POST

Url : https://login.microsoftonline.com/your directory ID/oauth2/token 

    HEADERS:  Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    BODY: grant_type+=client_credentials&resource+=”your Function url”&client_id+++++=”the application that your register  id”&client_secret+=”the key you create”
```

> Please note that according to the Azure Resources
>   portal(https://resources.azure.com/), the default allowedAudiences is
>
> "https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"
>   So I add the https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/ as allowed
>   aduiences

enter image description here 
[image]
Then I can use the access token directly. I test it with postman.

enter image description here 
[image]

> Please note that if your azure function authentication level is not
>   anonymous, you need to add the function key