# Get bearer token with MSAL.NET to access App Service with EasyAuth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication, easy-auth

I have an Azure App Service which is authenticated using Azure AD EasyAuth.
[image: Configured AppService with AD]

[image: Configured AppService with AD 2]

I am trying to send a request from another App Service using C# and MSAL.NET (Microsoft.Identity.Client).

The authentication code looks like this

```cs
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(config.ClientId) // The Client ID in the App Registration connected to the App Service
    .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority)) // https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0
    .WithTenantId(config.TenantId) // Tenant Id Guid
    .Build();


// Used Scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
var credentials = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(config.Scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I get a bearer token successfully, but when I try to call the App Service with token injected to the headers I get a 401 and `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` :(

### Update 1:

I tried @Jim Xu answer and it's still giving me 401. It returns a `www-authenticate` header with the following value
[image: www-authenticate value]

The resource id is the same ClientId in the App Reg

### Update 2 - Solution

So to summarize the fix:

1. The requested scopes when calling `AcquireTokenForClient` should include `{Application ID Uri}/.default`
2. In EasyAuth configuration, the `Allowed Token Audiences` needs to be set to the `Application ID Uri` as well

Comment: Which api are you calling?

Comment: I am calling the App Service directly. I am authenticating the request (authorization header) with the bearer token aquired from calling the `AcquireTokenForClient`

Comment: Is your `scope` set as your api?

Comment: my scope is set to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call the Azure API app which enables easy auth, please refer to the following steps

1. Get the `Application ID URI` of the AD application you use to enable easy auth

a. In the **Azure portal** menu, select **Azure Active Directory** or search for and select **Azure Active Directory** from any page.

b. Select **App registrations** > **Owned applications** > **View all applications** in this directory. Select your web app name, and then select **Overview**.
[image]

2. code

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(config.ClientId) // The Client ID in the App Registration connected to the App Service
    .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority)) // https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0
    .WithTenantId(config.TenantId) // Tenant Id Guid
    .Build();


// Used Scopes: ["{Application ID URI}/.default"]
var credentials = await app.AcquireTokenForClient("{Application ID URI}/.default")
    .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025942/azure-active-directory-using-loginwithazureactivedirectory-and-expressmode/55036610#55036610).

Comment: it's still giving me 401. I updated my question with the result. Do I need to add a specific scope in the App Reg?

Comment: @Ayman Is that you use the same application to project your web API and require token to call the api.

Comment: sorry didn’t understand your comment

Comment: @Ayman I want to if you register a new Azure AD application to get AD token to call your web API.

Comment: I created a new `App Registration` and connected it to the `App Service` but still the same

Comment: @Ayman According to my understanding, you create a new Azure AD application to configure easy auth. Meanwhile, you also use the application to get the token and call the web api. Right?

Comment: Correct. The same app registration is used to configure easyauth and also used to get the token to call the web api

Comment: @Ayman Could you please provide  the screenshot of how you configure easy auth?

Comment: Updated the screen shots

Comment: @Ayman Please update the issue as `https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/` and add you the app id URL in Allowed Token Audiences

Comment: Yes that worked . So to summarize my issue, I needed to set the `scope` and the `Allowed Token Audiences` to the Application ID Uri