# Why is EasyAuth returning a 401 Unauthorized status when a client post an access token on /.auth/login/aad endpoint?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I started to migrate my Live SDK registered applications to the new Application Registration Portal as Microsoft is deprecating their support:

[image: Application Registration Portal]

I went on the App Registrations (Preview) page in the Azure Portal and choose to create a new application.

Then, I went to my Function App's `Authentication / Authorization` page to put the information of the newly registered AAD application.

My client iOS application is getting the `authorization code` first and then a valid `access token` from these endpoints:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

With the `access token` in hand, the iOS application is trying to `POST` the token on the AAD endpoint (`/.auth/login/aad`) but it fails.

However, if I get an `authorization code` and an `access token` using a google account and then `POST`ing the `access token` to the `/.auth/login/google` endpoint, it succeeds.

**Question**

Why is EasyAuth returning a `401 Unauthorized` status when a client post an `access token` on `/.auth/login/aad` endpoint?

**Update**

I am at a point where I am able to retrieve the access token from this token endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token` and using `Insomnia` / `Postman` to `POST` the following object `application/json` to the `/.auth/login/aad` endpoint:

```
{
    "access_token": "eY...."
}
```

The response that I get is a `401 Unauthorized` with the following message:

```
You do not have the permission to view this directory or page.
```

I am following the exact same procedure as I am doing for Google accounts. I also made sure that my registered application allows user from my Azure Active Directory as well as personal account. Here is a screenshot of these settings:

[image: AAD settings]

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**: You should be using "Azure Active Directory" authentication provider and then configure the details properly in two places, A) Your Function App and B) Azure AD App Registration.

**Detailed Steps**

I tried out creating a simple Azure AD Authenticated Azure Function with App Registration through  App Registrations (Preview). Here are the detailed steps I followed.

**A) Configuration steps for your Function App**

1. In Azure portal navigate to your Function App > Platform Features > Authentication/Authorization

   [image]
2. From Authentication Providers choose Azure Active Directory. On the configuration page choose "Advanced" for Management mode.

   ClientID - Take the application ID from your Azure AD App Registration

   IssuerURL - `https://sts.windows.net/<your Azure AD Tenant ID>/`

   Allowed Token Audience - `https://<yourfunctionappname>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

   Client Secret (Optional) - only relevant for web applications. Again pick the key/secret value from your Azure AD App Registration.

   [image]

**B) Configuration steps for your Azure AD App Registration**

1. Navigate to Azure AD > App Registrations (Preview) > Your existing app registration > Overview >

   Click on Redirect URIs and add the value we added in Allowed Token Audience above.

   ```
   https://<yourfunctionappname>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
   ```
2. Navigate to Azure AD > App Registrations (Preview) > Your existing app registration > Manifest > Edit and set

   ```
   "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true
   ```

Comment: The last step ( B) 2.) was missing on my side however I still get a `401 Unauthorized` response.

Comment: ok makes sense @Kzrystof .. One more thing I also notice is your `Action to take when request is not authenticated` is set to allow anonymous acess.. is that intentional? Also, does your Azure function have any endpoints that are simple GET? I ask because you could test directly in browser by hitting that endpoint first to see if just accessing the function is working before trying to do it from iOS device client.

Comment: I will try & poke at the service directly and see what is going on as soon as I can.

Comment: I did poke at a GET function that just printed the ClaimsPrincipal and it works. However, I am unable to get that authorization token from the /.auth/login/aad endpoint...

Answer (score 2):

You should select Azure Active Directory as the provider and not Microsoft. Then, select the "Management mode" as "Advanced" and add the App ID of the registered application.

There is a pretty good blog post here that explains the process: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/secure-azure-function-with-azure-ad/

See also: [Azure Function authentication using Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499971/azure-function-authentication-using-azure-active-directory)

Comment: I think I have done all that was needed however I still get an Unauthorized status code.

Comment: I saw on another post that this can sometimes be an issue with the "Authentication/Authorization" header and that it sometimes needs to be disabled for requests to be received. Have you seen the same?

Comment: The Authorization header with the bearer token? I actually added it at some point before calling /.auth/login/aad but it did not change anything... So I removed it.