# Azure Functions returns "401 Unauthorized" only with Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-functions

I have some troubles trying to call an Azure Function [(code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOlXu.png) with Postman.

I have already set up the [Authentication / Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbknp.png) and [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC3S7.png).

It's working with my browser (with login page).

But when I try to use Postman, I'm getting 401 :

**"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."**

I also tried to use the Postman built-in [(see configuration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoHNZ.png) Oauth2 to login. I can successfully get the [tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsvaI.png) (access and refresh). But it seems that my API request to functions are not working...

Here is the final API Call: [postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxoiY.png)

The aad tenant_id starts with **8d6**, the application client_id starts with **226**, and the app secret ends with **Av2**.

Is there anything wrong ... ? It looks like actually, Azure Functions handle only Cookies for the authentication, that's why it's working with the browser and not Postman. How can I make it works with the header Authorization / Bearer ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499971/azure-function-authentication-using-azure-active-directory

Comment: Already tried ... Still not working

Comment: Did you try using the x-zumo-auth header?

Comment: Look at the value of the access token through jwt.js and see whether the audience claim value equals the id of your function app as registered in AAD? I suspect that when you accessed the API through the browser, EasyAuth executed OIDC authentication to your Function and this returned an id_token with the id the function as aud. However, in your Postman you are not specifying a resource or scope so the token you get is for Graph API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you got the access token is not correct. Just like @Marc said, in your Postman you are not specifying a resource or scope. The postman get new access token tool only has the scope parameter, so you should use the v2.0 endpoint to get the access token.

**Auth URL:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

**Access Token URL:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Scope:**

```
{clientId}/.default
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, it works ! You were right, the scope was missing ... Is there a lot of difference between the default and the v2.0 endpoint ?

Comment: @monsty See the difference here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison

Comment: You sir/madam are brilliant. The client_id/.default scope is what did it for me. I couldn't just use the graph scope.