# Authenticate Azure Functions

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-functions-docker

I am using a HTTP Function App, I would like to authenticate it using **client id** and **function keys** (inside my function) using **python**.

I have a API Management setup for the current service but would like to authenticate on function app level.

Thanks

Comment: There is not a question here. Please let us know what you've tried, what's not working, and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

For this one of the workaround is that you can set its Authorization level to Function.

[image]

**Note:** Make sure you are providing function key         as a URL query string parameter in code property **(i.e., `https://< Your Function App>.azurewebsites.net/api/< Your Function Name>?code=< Your Function Key>`)**. Alternatively, If you are calling function from postman you can just add `x-functions-key` header and set function key to it.

You can find all the function keys from **Trigger >> Function Keys**

[image]

but from the [Official Documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#authorization-keys) you can see that it is not a good practice to distribute shared secret in public apps.

> If your function is being called from a public client, you may want to consider implementing another security mechanism

Alternatively, you can use AAD to authenticate your Function App (i.e., Through App registration).
For more information, you can refer [Azure Function authentication using Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499971/azure-function-authentication-using-azure-active-directory)